# How to tell the amount of tablespace that would be freed by rebuilding indexes

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I would only like to rebuild my table indexes if doing so would release more than 2gb tablespace.  How can I determine the amount of tablespace that would be freed by rebuilding indexes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_space.htm#i1002659) to estimate the amount of space used
after the index is rebuilt.  Subtracting that from DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES will give you an estimate of the space saved.

The example below shows DBMS_SPACE making a fairly accurate prediction about the space-savings of rebuilding an unusually bad index.  The package
requires gathering statistics, so you may want to read about potential issues caused by gathering statistics from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265536/409172)
slightly related answer.

First, create a table and sample data, and gather statistics.

```
drop table test1 purge;
create table test1(a number, b number, c number);

insert /*+ append */ into test1 select level, level, level
from dual connect by level <= 500000;
commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST1');
end;
/
```

This shows DBMS_SPACE making an accurate prediction about the cost of a new index.

```
declare
    v_used_bytes number;
    v_alloc_bytes number;
begin
    dbms_space.create_index_cost(
        ddl => 'create index test1_idx on test1(a, b, c)'
        ,used_bytes => v_used_bytes
        ,alloc_bytes => v_alloc_bytes
    );
    dbms_output.put_line('Esimated Bytes: '||
        trim(to_char(v_alloc_bytes,'999,999,999')));
end;
/

Esimated Bytes: 14,680,064


create index test1_idx on test1(a, b, c);
select trim(to_char(bytes, '999,999,999')) actual_bytes
    from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TEST1_IDX';

ACTUAL_BYTES
------------
15,728,640
```

Now simulate a "bad" index.  A common myth is that indexes do not automatically re-use space.  The real issue is that indexes will not re-claim the space for a leaf block until every entry is removed.  This example deletes 95% of the rows, but the amount of space is the same.

```
delete from test1 where mod(a, 20) <> 1;
commit;
select trim(to_char(bytes, '999,999,999')) actual_bytes
    from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TEST1_IDX';

ACTUAL_BYTES
------------
15,728,640
```

Re-gather stats, and now the estimate is very similar to the actual size after a rebuild.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST1');
end;
/

declare
    v_used_bytes number;
    v_alloc_bytes number;
begin
    dbms_space.create_index_cost(
        ddl => 'create index test1_idx on test1(a, b, c)'
        ,used_bytes => v_used_bytes
        ,alloc_bytes => v_alloc_bytes
    );
    dbms_output.put_line('Esimated Bytes: '||
        trim(to_char(v_alloc_bytes,'999,999,999')));
end;
/

Esimated Bytes: 720,896


alter index test1_idx rebuild;
select trim(to_char(bytes, '999,999,999')) actual_bytes
    from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TEST1_IDX';

ACTUAL_BYTES
------------
851,968
```