# How to Get all table space name, Allocated size, Free size, Capacity from single query?

Tags: oracle

How can i get the information about all tables space in my database in below format.

```
TABLESPACE_NAME | FILE_NAME |  ALLOCATED_MB  | FREE_MB |  CAPACITY |
```

Is there way to store daily size of all table-space in another table automatically ?. Actually i need to prepare checklist regarding table space on daily basis. So I wan't to create front end which email me the table space size details automatically on the basis of that table which store the information about table space size on daily basis..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate tables size in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264914/how-do-i-calculate-tables-size-in-oracle)

Comment: Don't be confused, I am looking for table spaces not for table size.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the below query to get all tablespace details in oracle. Assuming that you have the necessary privileges to access dba tables.

```
SELECT a.file_name,
       substr(A.tablespace_name,1,14) tablespace_name,
       trunc(decode(A.autoextensible,'YES',A.MAXSIZE-A.bytes+b.free,'NO',b.free)/1024/1024) free_mb,
       trunc(a.bytes/1024/1024) allocated_mb,
       trunc(A.MAXSIZE/1024/1024) capacity,
       a.autoextensible ae
FROM (
     SELECT file_id, file_name,
            tablespace_name,
            autoextensible,
            bytes,
            decode(autoextensible,'YES',maxbytes,bytes) maxsize
     FROM   dba_data_files
     GROUP BY file_id, file_name,
              tablespace_name,
              autoextensible,
              bytes,
              decode(autoextensible,'YES',maxbytes,bytes)
     ) a,
     (SELECT file_id,
             tablespace_name,
             sum(bytes) free
      FROM   dba_free_space
      GROUP BY file_id,
               tablespace_name
      ) b
WHERE a.file_id=b.file_id(+)
AND A.tablespace_name=b.tablespace_name(+)
ORDER BY A.tablespace_name ASC;
```

Comment: With some modification this query works perfectly, but Is there any way to store these information in another table automatically rather running Insert Query on daily basis.

Comment: Currently i don't think there is an option to store the information automatically.

Comment: Instead, you can create a procedure to compare the difference in tablespace size and run on daily basis using `dbms_scheduler`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.tablespace_name,a.file_name,a.bytes/1024/1024 TABLESPACE_SIZE_MB,
Sum(b.bytes)/1024/1024 FREE_IN_MB from dba_free_space b,dba_data_files a
Where a.tablespace_name = b.tablespace_name
AND a.file_id = b.file_id
GROUP by a.tablespace_name, a.file_name,a.bytes/1024/1024
Order by a.tablespace_name, a.file_name;
```

you can run this query this may help.

Answer (score 2):

Above are useful. Hope this may also helpful here:

https://ora-data.blogspot.in/2016/12/how-to-find-details-of-tablespace.html

Check the Tablespace details with different command, above command may not work:

```
SQL>select round((bytes/1024)/1024,0) "Used Space(MB)",
round(total,0) "Allocated size(MB)",
round(max,0) "Maximum allowable(MB)",
round(max-(BYTES/1024)/1024,0) "Effective free(MB)",
round(((max-(BYTES/1024)/1024)/max)*100,2) "FREE(%)"
from SYS.SM$TS_USED,
(select sum((BYTES/1024)/1024) total, sum((decode(MAXBYTES,0,bytes,maxbytes)/1024)/1024) max
from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='&1') where tablespace_name='&1';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle refer below link :

[How do I calculate tables size in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264914/how-do-i-calculate-tables-size-in-oracle)

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2160787

```
COLUMN TABLE_NAME FORMAT A32
COLUMN OBJECT_NAME FORMAT A32
COLUMN OWNER FORMAT A10

SELECT
   owner, table_name, TRUNC(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) Meg
FROM
(SELECT segment_name table_name, owner, bytes
 FROM dba_segments
 WHERE segment_type = 'TABLE'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.table_name, i.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_indexes i, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = i.index_name
 AND   s.owner = i.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'INDEX'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'LOBSEGMENT'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.index_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'LOBINDEX')
WHERE owner in UPPER('&owner')
GROUP BY table_name, owner
HAVING SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 > 10  /* Ignore really small tables */
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) desc
;
```

In **SQL** refer below

[Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Comment: Thank You, This exactly i am looking for but i wan't to list all tablespaces not space of tables.