# How to retrieve default/current datafile name and tablespace name through SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

If i have just a oracle schema name then how can i retrieve all the properties/attributes of that schema in respect to the DB name, Datafile name and tablespace name.
Along with the space allocated to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate tables size in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264914/how-do-i-calculate-tables-size-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

The dba_users view gives you schema name and default tablespace for that schema.

```
select * from dba_users
```

Subsequently you can query dba_data_files. But not all data for a schema might be in the default tablespace. Better check dba_segments for that schema.

```
select segment_name,tablespace_name from dba_segments
where owner='YOUR_SCHEMA'
```