# query to check the size in GB of the table per specific component

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have a requirement to check the space occupied by a specific table per day per system, just a short back ground i have some 10 systems from each system we process the daily etl loads and the counts can be observed based in the date field.

**Database oracle 11g**

**size per GB**

example

```
SYSTEM PROCESS_DATE count(*)

RETAIL 26.02.2021   100
PHARMACY 26.02.2021 200
BANKING  26.02.2021 300
```

**query 1 - to check the daily counts per system**

```
select distinct system,count(*) from AUDIT_SCH.DWH_ADT_TBL
where trunc(process_date)=trunc(sysdate)
group by system
order by count(*) desc;
```

but what i want is how to capture the space of daily loads consumed per system from this table ? , is this possible

it's confusing checking various suggestions  below is the reference

[How do I calculate tables size in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264914/how-do-i-calculate-tables-size-in-oracle)

any suggestions with query ?

Comment: Can you write a query against a table when you don't know the structure of the table? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [VSIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VSIZE.html#GUID-CDDB2A17-9398-4AF8-96FB-4297DDA2665B) to sum the number of bytes used in each column, per system:

```
select
    system, count(*),
    round(sum
    (
        nvl(vsize(system), 0) +
        nvl(vsize(process_date), 0) +
        nvl(vsize(column1), 0) +
        nvl(vsize(column2), 0)
        --Add all other columns here
    )/1024/1024/1024) gb
from DWH_ADT_TBL
where trunc(process_date)=trunc(sysdate)
group by system
order by count(*) desc;
```

Unfortunately, calculating the size of things in a database can be ridiculously complicated. You may need to worry about:

1. **Overhead.** The `VSIZE` function does not account for row overhead, block overhead, segment overhead, and unused space in files/ASM diskgroups/volumes, etc.
2. **Compression.** If the table, tablespace, or LOBs are compressed or encrypted, the `VSIZE` will incorrectly return the uncompressed size.
3. **Indexes.** `VSIZE` does not include index sizes. But if you're only interested in comparing systems, then the percentage of data will still be the same even if the absolute sizes are off. (Unless you have indexed columns that are only used by one system.)
4. **LOBs.** You may need to use `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH` to calculate the size of LOBs. For CLOBs you may need to multiple the result by 2 depending on the characterset - for UCS2, each character uses 2 bytes.

But in practice the above query is still good enough to give you a decent understanding of where the space is used.

If you have multiple tables with many columns you could generate the queries using the data dictionary, by querying from `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Comment: fantastic way to check , how to identify whether the results are in GB/MB/TB usually we put some thing like  example - ROUND(BYTES) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS GB but when i am trying to test it it's not working    ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 12

Comment: after using the updated logic i am getting 0 rows

Comment: @rakesh That may be because of `trunc(process_date)=trunc(sysdate)` - maybe data isn't loaded on the weekend so there are no rows today? Try with `trunc(process_date) = date '2021-02-26'` instead.

Comment: i have tried that as well i have also switched the past days i can see the counts and if i apply newly updated condition under the GB section 0

Comment: @rakesh Maybe the data isn't large enough - try using `1024/1024` for MB instead of `1024/1024/1024` for GB.